# Does a function's pointer to char needs memory allocation in C

Tags: c

Defining a function in c using this structures of data:

```
typedef struct {
   int number;
   char name[25];
} person;
person rep[100];
int key=0;
```

Is there any problem with memory allocation when defining this function:
(i'm just a beginner: i don't know what memory allocation means)

```
void add_person(int num, char *name){
   if (key<100){
      rep[key].number = num;
      strcpy(rep[key].name, name);
      key++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function's pointer is something completely different than this.

What you have is a function with a `char *` (`char` pointer). If you call this function, you pass it the contents for a "new" `person` struct.

This `person` struct contains a (rather small) array where the name can be held, so memory allocation (which means reserving a memory area for dedicated use) is implied there.

But be warned: what do you think will happen if the caller passes a string with more than 25 characters? Right, it will "destroy" the contents of the memory area behind it.

So you'll have to pay attention and use `strncpy(rep[key].name, name, sizeof rep[key].name)`. As the creator of `strncpy()` seems to have slept ("No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than num"), you'll have to add this null-character - which indicates the end of a string in C - by yourself:

```
rep[key].name[sizeof rep[key].name - 1] = '\0'
```

If the string was shorter, `strcpy()` has added its own `'\0'`, if not, we cut it here.

Comment: You may find value in reading [this article about `strncpy()`](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Quite interesting, but essentially the same as I said.

Comment: The difference is in approach: You're expressed opinion is that the lack of null termination on a full buffer is a result of the designer of the function sleeping on the job, the approach of that article is that the function was simply designed for a completely different purpose.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Ok, maybe, but if it was supposed to have a different purpose than handling strings, it shouldn't have been named misleading. But we can now argument as we want, the facts are made and nothing will change on this function.

Comment: I agree that the name is misleading, I'm not arguing against that at all. I was just offering an alternate perspective on the purpose of the function.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Well, then thanks for this point of view. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for any explicit allocations in your code (as shown). The definition

```
person rep[100];
```

makes the compiler allocate space for 100 `person` structures. And with the member-field definition

```
char name[25];
```

each `person` structure have space for 25 characters in `name` (i.e. a string with up to 24 characters, plus the string terminator).

Answer (score 1):

For your add_person, you don't need to worry about memory leaking.
But you need to either add key as a global variable (next to rep) or define it as a static variable inside of add_person like this:

```
static int key = 0;
```

But you have an issue with this line

```
strcpy(rep[key].name, name);
```

If the input name to add_person is longer than 24 characters, it will result in strcpy writing outside of rep.name.
At length 25, the name no longer is null-terminated, causing any function reading on that to read past it and (best case) into the next person (their number showing up as either garbage or another random character), or (worst case) outside of the rep array and your program segfaults.

You should check that name is shorter than 25.

The correct thing to do would to have char* name; in function, then do the following copy in add_person:

```
rep[key].name = malloc( strlen(name)+1 );
strcpy( rep[key].name, name );
```

In this case, you should make a function to free persons

```
free_person(struct person* p)
{
  free(p->name);
}
```

Comment: "The correct thing to do" rather should read "Another, more flexible  way to do it". The way the OP did it is not wrong per se, if he uses `strncpy()`.

Comment: @glglgl The way the OP did it is not wrong per se, even if he doesn't use `strncpy()`, so long as he uses some method of ensuring his strings are short enough for the target buffer.

Answer (score 0):

your function definition is good

just a thing concerning the `key` variable: It should be defined as global variable

Comment: and how do you want to access it from outside then?

Answer (score 0):

The line `person rep[100];` reserves space for you to store 100 person objects, so no, there isn't a problem with memory allocation.

In real life, you would also need to be more careful that you didn't write a name longer than 24 characters into the `name` member.